# How to re-execute function in ThreadPoolExecutor in case of error?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm trying this [example code for python's `ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) from python's `concurrent.futures` documentation. Specifically

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

How can I re-send a call to the executor if an exception is generated inside the `concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url)` loop? Basically I simply want to retry failed jobs.

I've tried simply calling something like `executor.submit(...)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Futures are realized after the failure. The failure is their value. Therefore, you cannot re-execute them, you must create a new Future.

Since you have the URL, you could do it on the error handler and, after the Futures in `future_to_url` complete, iterate over the new Futures which were added to a different collection.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood it correctly. But if I did, what happens if there is another error in the other collection?

Comment: It has to be a cycle which should happen with as many times as you'd like to retry.

Comment: Ok, I suppose there are better ways than a while loop to handle that kind of situations, I'll wait a bit to see if others come up with more elegant solutions. Thanks for now

Comment: @crash I guess not. :)

Comment: thanks for writing the comment, I would've never remembered this!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question recently and like @Javier says I ended up needing fresh futures each time. And I used a while loop like @Javier hinted at as well.

Reframing with respect to your url based problem setup, I wanted to make it easier to simulate timeouts/failure so below if "fake" is in the url then I simulate the behavior.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import urllib
from random import randint
from collections import defaultdict

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']
URLS = [f"http://fake{i}.com" for i in range(20)]

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    if "fake" in url:
        time.sleep(1)
        x = randint(1, 10)
        if x <= 5:
            return {"timeout": True, "error": "SimulatedTimeout", "url": url}
        elif x in [6, 7]:
            return {"error": "SomeOtherError", "url": url}
        else:
            return {"data": "<html>" + str(randint(1, 999999)) + "</html>", "url": url}

    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
            data = conn.read()
            return {"data": data, "url": url}
    # except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    except Exception as e:
        if "TimeoutError" in repr(e):
            return {"timeout": True, "error": repr(e), "url": url}
        else:
            return {"error": repr(e), "url": url}

todo = [{"url": url} for url in URLS]
final_results = []
retry_counts = defaultdict(int)
max_retries = 5
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    while True:
        future_list = [executor.submit(load_url, item["url"], 60) for item in todo]
        todo = []
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_list):
            result = future.result()
            if result.get("data"):
                final_results.append({**result, "retries": retry_counts[result["url"]]})
            elif result.get("error") and not result.get("timeout"):
                final_results.append({**result, "retries": retry_counts[result["url"]]})
            elif result.get("timeout") and retry_counts[result["url"]] < max_retries:
                retry_counts[result["url"]] += 1
                todo.append({"url": result["url"]})
            else:
                final_results.append({**result, "reached_max_retries": True, "retries": retry_counts[result["url"]]})
        if len(final_results) == len(URLS):
            print("Done!")
            break
        else:
            print(f"we are now {len(final_results)} out of {len(URLS)}")
```

that produced the output,

```
we are now 10 out of 20
we are now 11 out of 20
we are now 16 out of 20
we are now 17 out of 20
we are now 18 out of 20
Done!

In [45]: pd.DataFrame.from_records(final_results)
Out[45]: 
               error                url  retries                 data timeout reached_max_retries
0     SomeOtherError   http://fake0.com        0                  NaN     NaN                 NaN
1                NaN   http://fake2.com        0  <html>124983</html>     NaN                 NaN
2     SomeOtherError   http://fake3.com        0                  NaN     NaN                 NaN
3                NaN   http://fake7.com        0  <html>459880</html>     NaN                 NaN
4     SomeOtherError  http://fake10.com        0                  NaN     NaN                 NaN
5                NaN  http://fake13.com        0  <html>598498</html>     NaN                 NaN
6                NaN  http://fake15.com        0  <html>477976</html>     NaN                 NaN
7                NaN  http://fake16.com        0  <html>748633</html>     NaN                 NaN
8     SomeOtherError  http://fake17.com        0                  NaN     NaN                 NaN
9                NaN  http://fake19.com        0  <html>104853</html>     NaN                 NaN
10               NaN   http://fake9.com        1  <html>677035</html>     NaN                 NaN
11               NaN   http://fake8.com        2  <html>249557</html>     NaN                 NaN
12               NaN   http://fake5.com        2  <html>516063</html>     NaN                 NaN
13    SomeOtherError   http://fake6.com        2                  NaN     NaN                 NaN
14    SomeOtherError  http://fake11.com        2                  NaN     NaN                 NaN
15               NaN  http://fake12.com        2   <html>66441</html>     NaN                 NaN
16               NaN   http://fake1.com        3  <html>604868</html>     NaN                 NaN
17    SomeOtherError  http://fake18.com        4                  NaN     NaN                 NaN
18  SimulatedTimeout   http://fake4.com        5                  NaN    True                True
19  SimulatedTimeout  http://fake14.com        5                  NaN    True                True
```